# How to insert multiple rows in a table by user input in Oracle 19C?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I want to insert multiple rows in a table by user input in PL/SQL. This is my sql code: my table and my pl/sql block

```
CREATE TABLE tabletest
(
    id NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    anytext VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
/
DECLARE
    nrows INT := '&Input_N_Rows';
BEGIN
    FOR n IN 1..nrows LOOP
        INSERT INTO tabletest VALUES('&id', '&anytext');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But, it throws me an error

> Error report - 
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (VENTA.SYS_C007513)
> violated  
> ORA-06512: at line 5
>
> 00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
>
> *Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
> For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
>
> *Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Please, help me.

Comment: Once you define the substitution variables their value is fixed. You're not redefining them, so your primary key '&id' is always the same value. Hence the unique constraint violation. Better to make your insert like this: `insert into tabletest values (n, '&anytext');` Your PK then changes with the index of your loop. Your text will always be the same value, but it won't violate any constraints. Of course this will only work once; the second time you run the procedure you'll repeat PK values again.

Comment: PL/SQL is not really intended for user-interactivity. It doesn't play well with SQL\*Plus commands. Presumably you are just experimenting with the language, but there are other approaches to do this.